# how to add text from a string resource as a paragraph text in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I have a Flow Document and in its paragraphs I want to add text from a string resource, how do you do that?

```
<FlowDocument>
      <Paragraph>
         //string from resource//
      </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding in xaml:

```
<FlowDocument>
      <Paragraph>
        <Run Text={StsticResource yourString} />
     </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

in code behind :
add `x:name="paragraph"` in xaml.
add like this in code behind:

```
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(This.Resources["yourString"]));
```